# How do I invite someone to a guild in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to get my discord bot to message a user with a link to join the guild, but I'm having trouble with who to send it to. Since they're not in the guild you can't message them.

```
if (!args[0]) return message.reply("Who would you like to invite? For example: funny#6942");
    message.channel.createInvite({
            unique: true,
            maxUses: 1,
            maxAge: 8 * 60 * 1000
        })
        .then(invite => {
            var invited = args[0];
            message.invited.send("https://discord.gg/" + invite.code);
            //dm person with the invite code
        });
```

I'm still somewhat new to Discord's JavaScript API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for that user in all cached users as in

```js
client.users.cache.find((x) => {
 x.tag == `${args[0]}` 
}).send("https://discord.gg/" + invite.code); // This would return a GuildMember object and send the code to that person
```

There could be instances where the user is uncached, in those cases it's best to ask for an `Id` to the user and use
`<Client>#user#fetch()` on them although if your bot is small there's no need to worry!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to surround `args[0]` with curly braces like `${args[0]}`

Comment: Yeah my bad you gotta add placeholders if they're in q string

Comment: Oh wait you can just forego the template literal entirely and just do `x.tag == args[0]`

Comment: yup you can do that too although `x.tag` returns a string I suppose so it's a better practice to equate a string to a string :)

Comment: It's just giving me the error "Cannot read property 'send' of undefined"

Comment: Could you pelase log the user since if it comes out as unefined it simply means that the user is unavailable to the client's cache meaning the bot and the user share no mutual servers

Comment: oh the problem is that ur not returning anything from the `.find()` function - try `client.users.cache.find((x) => x.tag == args[0]).send("whatever");` instead. If it still errors out, it might be that the user isn't in the cache, so you can do `client.users.fetch().then((users) => users.find((x) => x.tag == args[0]).send("whatever"))` instead

Comment: It might not be available to the guild altogether is also a possibility, please check the solutions given by chickensalt and tally them with mine